# Export iPhone 3GS contacts into iCloud

Tags: icloud, iphone

I bought an iPhone 6 and I would like to use all the contacts from my iPhone 3GS.

Some of the contacts were stored in iCloud. The other ~480 contacts are on my iPhone 3GS. How can I transfer these to my iPhone 6?

Answer (score 1):

Using an applitcation like iBackupBot found here:http://www.icopybot.com/itunes-backup-manager.htm

You can plug in your iphone 3gs and make a backup, it will back up all contacts Like so:
[image]

Now you go ahead and plug in your new iphone 6 and click the restore button.

Give it a minute or two, depending on your computer and you should have all your contacts on your brand new iPhone 6!

Hope you enjoy the iPhone 6, I know I am!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to make the "on the iPhone" contacts go up to iCloud.

First, backup the iPhone in iTunes so if everything goes wrong you can go back to the way things were. Then for good measure, backup your computer too, particularly the contacts/calendars/etc. that get stored in iCloud.

Now that everything is safely backed up, on the iPhone, delete the iCloud account from the phone, and when it asks you if you want to keep copies of the iCloud data (contacts, calendars, etc) on the phone, tell it to delete them all from the phone. Once this is done, your iPhone should only have the data that is NOT in iCloud. Now you should re-setup your iCloud account on this phone. I am pretty sure that setting up iCloud on the phone will cause all of the phone's "local" data to merge with the data in iCloud. Once all the phone data is in the iCloud system, you can again sign the old iPhone out of iCloud (remember to remove FindMyiPhone if you are passing this phone on to someone else) and when you sign the new iPhone into iCloud, it should have all of your data.

If you don't want this data in iCloud, the method that KAS suggested might be better.